# SQL Server Line Constructor or version of ST_MakeLine(pt1,pt2)?

Tags: sql-server, spatial

PostGIS provides a function called [`ST_MakeLine(pt1,pt2)`](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html). It's great for constructing lines. MySQL does the same with [`LineString(pt1,pt2)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-mysql-specific-functions.html#function_linestring). **What do you call the SQL Server analog that takes two Points and constructs a LineString?**

I looked up [LineString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/linestring), but didn't see it mentioned.

Here is a [test case on dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=2486c6a2cc6404b7a0e8ae30b5bdc61d).

Sample data,

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (
  pt1 geometry,
  pt2 geometry,
);

INSERT INTO #tmp(pt1,pt2) VALUES
  (geometry::Point(1,1,4326), geometry::Point(2,2,4326)),
  (geometry::Point(2,2,4326), geometry::Point(5,5,4326)),
  (geometry::Point(3,3,4326), geometry::Point(4,4,4326)),
  (geometry::Point(4,4,4326), geometry::Point(3,3,4326)),
  (geometry::Point(5,5,4326), geometry::Point(4,4,4326));
```

Query

```
SELECT pt1, pt2
  'My Line' AS line -- what goes here
FROM #tmp;
```

And I'm wanting "My Line" to be the `LineString`.

```
pt1         pt2         line
POINT (1 1) POINT (2 2) My Line
POINT (2 2) POINT (5 5) My Line
POINT (3 3) POINT (4 4) My Line
POINT (4 4) POINT (3 3) My Line
POINT (5 5) POINT (4 4) My Line
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try [`ShortestLineTo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/shortestlineto-geometry-data-type):

```
SELECT
  pt1.ToString(),
  pt2.ToString(),
  pt1.ShortestLineTo(pt2).ToString() AS line -- what goes here
FROM #tmp;
```

Returns

```
POINT (1 1)   POINT (2 2)   LINESTRING (1 1, 2 2)
POINT (2 2)   POINT (5 5)   LINESTRING (2 2, 5 5)
POINT (3 3)   POINT (4 4)   LINESTRING (3 3, 4 4)
POINT (4 4)   POINT (3 3)   LINESTRING (4 4, 3 3)
POINT (5 5)   POINT (4 4)   LINESTRING (5 5, 4 4)
```

Comment: great answer, that's exactly what I'm looking for. I just was being lazy and didn't want to write the literals, I took your example though and moved it up into the question to keep it simpler.. `ShortestLineTo()` is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: It is unlikely to happen, but I struck a "got ya" the other day with the Geography.  If you start from 0 -180 and go to 0 -179 then it will change the start point to 0 180.  Generally not a problem until you try to map it with ESRI Mapservice